# Load data to hive array of struct

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have data in CSV looks like

```
David,"""SMARTPHONE,6""|""COMPUTER,3""|""LAPTOP,1"""
```

I try to load this to my hive table

```
create table user_device(name string, devices array<struct<devicename: string, number : int>>) 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
collection items terminated by '|'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 'maprfs:///user/david/';
```

I expected to see

```
[{"devicename":"SMARTPHONE","number":6},{"devicename":"COMPUTER","number":3},{"devicename":"LAPTOP","number":1}]
```

But when I try to query the table, I see the array of struct is

```
[{"devicename":"\"\"\"SMARTPHONE","number":null}]
```

Rest of the array and struct are gone.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Thanks
David

Answer (score 0):

He is a code I used. In the approach I used python for cleaning before proceeding to HQL queries. So after doing some wrangling steps, I have a file like this below (saved without `indices` and `headers`) in my local file system since its a small file:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

    Name  devicename number
0  David  SMARTPHONE      6
1           COMPUTER      3
2             LAPTOP      1
```

Then a temp table `tempt` is created and populated with data from LFS or HDFS:

```
create table tempt
(
name       string,
devicename string,
number     int
)
row format delimited 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
load data local inpath '/path_to_file' overwrite into table tempt;

select * from tempt;
+--------------------+--------------------------+----------------------+--+
| tempt.name         | tempt.devicename         | tempt.number         |
+--------------------+--------------------------+----------------------+--+
| David              | SMARTPHONE               | 6                    |
|                    | COMPUTER                 | 3                    |
|                    | LAPTOP                   | 1                    |
+--------------------+--------------------------+----------------------+--+
```

And now

```
Insert overwrite table user_device
select name,
array(named_struct("devicename",devicename,"number",number)) from tempt;

select * from user_device;
```

and the output now is as you expected.

```
+-----------------+-------------------------------------------+--+
|user_device.name |            user_device.devices            |
+-----------------+-------------------------------------------+--+
| David           | [{"devicename":"SMARTPHONE","number":6}]  |
|                 | [{"devicename":"COMPUTER","number":3}]    |
|                 | [{"devicename":"LAPTOP","number":1}]      |
+-----------------+-------------------------------------------+--+
```

Cheers!